# How to restore removed file

Tags: fedora

am using linux, Fedora distro. I suddenly removed one file using in command prompt a command that delete a repository. Is there a method to restore this file without reinstalling all repository ? If not how to reinstall correct ? Thank You. P.S I was trying to install mysql img with code
[image]

I was using this command:

```
sudo rpm -e --nodeps mysql-community-libs mysql-community-common mysql-community-server
```

Comment: what do you mean with "repository"? Clearly, the service file that was removed is integrally part of the packages you uninstalled. You can't make use of that file without the rest of the package.

Comment: `rpm -e ` deletes packages. Not sure what you're doing. `mysqld.service` is generated  (it's a symlink) automatically once you run `systemctl enable service`. Looks like you don't quite understand what you're doing.

Comment: The file is not useful without the rest of the packages that you deleted.

Comment: Until you become VERY familiar with RPM package management (and then only for very special instances), you really should just be using `dnf` to handle all your installs/updates/removes/etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `rpm -e` command will remove the specified packages, so your command would uninstall all three packages you specified. That would mean removing quite a lot of files, not just one. Normally the `rpm -e` will do its job silently.

The message about removing the `mysqld.service` file is a side effect of a package pre-removal script running `sysctemctl disable mysqld.service` as part of the uninstallation process. It **does not mean** only that file was deleted.

If the system has a connection to a package repository, the effects of your `rpm -e` command can be basically reversed with `yum install mysql-community-libs mysql-community-common mysql-community-server; systemctl enable mysql`. But after this, you might have a newer version of MySQL than you originally did... usually that might be a good thing, but it's possible some software might depend on having a particular old version. If that is the case, then you would have to read the logs in the `/var/log` directory to find out the exact version numbers of the removed packages, and add the version numbers to the package specifications of the `yum install` command.